# SSAS Tabular model: two relations with the same dimension table

Tags: ssas, tabular, dimensions, ssas-tabular, fact

I need to create a tabular model with ssas but in a fact table I have two relations with the same dimension (time).

How is it best to handle this?
Duplicating the dimensions table ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer, 
this model is going to be used by business user and the haven't deep knowledge of dax.

I can't develop all the measures several times (also because it is about 4 dates per table and about fifty measures).

Whant do you think about this:
https://www.biinsight.com/role-playing-dimension-ssas-tabular/#more-1068

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to duplicate the dimension table. You can create both relationships, setting one as `INACTIVE`. Once this relationship is set up you can invoke the inactive relationship using the [USERELATIONSHIP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/userelationship-function-dax) function. This will essentially make the relationship `ACTIVE` for that measure.

The following links give a great explanation followed by some examples.

[Link 1](https://carldesouza.com/power-bi-dax-userelationship-multiple-dates/)

[Link 2](https://businessintelligist.com/2014/11/26/tutorial-how-to-use-single-date-dimension-in-your-model-using-userelationship-function/)